# Make button for Bootstrap tabs to cycle all tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I've created a button that navigates to the next tab - once the next button reaches the last tab it's stops , how can i set it to start over by reaching the last tab?

I want to be able to use the next button to simply cycle through all the tabs....

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/808cvx43/)

Here is the basic js

```
 $('.next_btn').click(function() {

    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with http://jsfiddle.net/808cvx43/2/

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
  
  $('.next_btn').click(function() {
  if($('.nav-tabs > li:last-child').hasClass('active')){
     $('.nav > li:last-child').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav > li:first-child').addClass('active');
    }else{
     $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="next_btn">
Next Tab
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that method but i forgot to remove the classes... so it didn't worked..